# How do I create a static method that returns a reference to an object of that class?

Tags: c++, object, reference, declaration, static-methods

Im working on a programming assignment involving the use of static variables/methods. This is one of the requirements, and I'm not exactly sure the proper syntax for declaring it in the header and defining it in the class file:

"Declare a static method of the class with a return type of a reference to an object of the class; name this method “instance”."

heres my guess for declaring:

```
static &Singleton instance();
```

heres my guess for defining:

```
static &Singleton::Singleton instance(){
    static myObj;
    return myObj;
}
```

I don't think thats correct.. Could anyone confirm/correct me? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got it almost right.

Declaration:

```
static Singleton& instance();
```

Definition:

```
Singleton& Singleton::instance() {
  static Singleton myObj;
  return myObj;
}
```